# Dynamic HTML Display Current date

Tags: javascript, html

I have a quick question.. I am using website builder called 'clickfunnels', and they dont support feature that would allow me to display current date via website. But, I can add custom html to it...

With that said, I found an old Stack Overflow question which is very close to fixing my problem, but this person wanted the current date to show +1 or the next day than the current date.

Here is the coding I tried, which works perfect on the website, I just need it to show the current date and not +1.

Can anyone please give me some tips on editing this? It would be greatly appreciated!!! Thank You!

```
<span id="spanDate"></span>
 <script type="text/javascript">
           var months = 
['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
'August','September','October','November','December'];       
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime() + (1000*3600*24));       
document.getElementById("spanDate").innerHTML = 
months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + " " + tomorrow.getDate()+ ", " + 
tomorrow.getFullYear();
</script>
```

Comment: romove the `tomorrow.setTime(...)` line. You might also want to rename tomorrow to today to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove  `(1000*3600*24)` from tomorrow. It is adding extra day

```js
           var months = 
['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
'August','September','October','November','December'];       
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime());       
document.getElementById("spanDate").innerHTML = 
months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + " " + tomorrow.getDate()+ ", " + 
tomorrow.getFullYear();
```

```html
<span id="spanDate"></span>
```

Comment: Ashay, that worked perfect. First try. Thank you so much again!!! Trying to learn more on this coding, but as I am sure you already know it can be a headache to newbies. THANKS!!!

Comment: If it helped you mark it as correct so that it can help others too

Comment: Ashay, is it much work to show the date like this.... Wednesday, February 6, 2019

Comment: Like months name you have to create a week array and put all the week days in it, and then print them the say way you printed the month name

Comment: O heck, kinda understand. Don't know if this is okay to ask for this site, but is it possible to pay you to set this up for me by chance?

Comment: not the right place actually. Hit me up on my twitter. Link on profile page

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `setTime` line

```html
<span id="spanDate"></span>
 <script type="text/javascript">
           var months = 
['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
'August','September','October','November','December'];       
var tomorrow = new Date();
/* tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime() + (1000*3600*24)); */       
document.getElementById("spanDate").innerHTML = 
months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + " " + tomorrow.getDate()+ ", " + 
tomorrow.getFullYear();
</script>
```